# Is my password visible over the wire when I push from Mercurial using a public WiFi?

Tags: encryption, windows-7, mercurial, https

If I push to Bitbucket like this:

```
C:\My Projects\repo>hg push https://user:passd@bitbucket.org/user/repo/
pushing to https://user:***@bitbucket.org/user/repo/
searching for changes
no changes found
```

The first line is what I type:

```
C:\My Projects\repo>hg push https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/repo/
```

But the message from Mercurial hides the typed password:

```
pushing to https://user:***@bitbucket.org/user/repo/
```

Does that mean my password is encrypted before it goes out over the public WiFi connection and is therefore safe?

Comment: You’re pushing to HTTPS so yes it is encrypted.

Comment: I reformulated the question so that is wasn't Starbucks specific. Let's reopen it so that we can answer it properly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If it uses SSL then it should be encrypted before password is sent. Whether mercurial uses it or not is specified in mercurial web server configuration.

> `push_ssl`
>   Whether to require that inbound pushes be transported over SSL to prevent password sniffing. Default is True.

[Link](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth)

Comment: He’s pushing to HTTPS...

Comment: Well it is slightly incorrect about the configuration. Anyway https is using SSL.